# C# - How to change culture without changing DateTime format

Tags: c#, multilingual, cultureinfo, culture

I have been used Resx file in ASP,net Web Form for implemention of multi language in an site.
for changing the language I should change below mesures:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

it seems that in new operating systems such as Microsoft Windows 10 , changing Culture may change the DateTime in a same way.
it cause a lot of problem for us
for example : The saving format for DateTime in database is Anno Domini but it change by changing Culture and save in database by other formats.
How should I change the Culture without changing the Date format?

Thanks

Comment: If you are saving DateTimes in the database as formatted strings, you have a *far* bigger problem than this one.

Comment: @iakobski I really didnt want to do that.I want to save them as DataTime.    ;]

Comment: Are you saving the DateTime in your database as string?  Or as DateTime data type.  Is you are data type the culture doesn't affect the DateTime value.  And you if it's a string, just format the string before every save/write to the database.

Comment: Did any of this helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following code to my OnLoad of master page to prevent using other cultures calendars

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat = New CultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement custom culture using [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8) class and derive datetime patterns from default or own culture :

```
public static class PersianDateExtensionMethods
{
    private static CultureInfo _culture;

    public static CultureInfo GetPersianCulture()
    {
        const string cultureName = "fa-IR";

        if (_culture == null)
        {
            _culture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);

            DateTimeFormatInfo formatInfo = _culture.DateTimeFormat;

            formatInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames = new[] { "ی", "د", "س", "چ", "پ", "ج", "ش" };
            formatInfo.DayNames = new[] { "یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "سه شنبه", "چهار شنبه", "پنجشنبه", "جمعه", "شنبه" };
            var monthNames = new[]
            {
                "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن",
                "اسفند",
                ""
            };
            formatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames = formatInfo.MonthNames = formatInfo.MonthGenitiveNames = formatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = monthNames;

            _culture.DateTimeFormat = new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat;

            Calendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();

            FieldInfo fieldInfo = _culture.GetType().GetField("calendar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (fieldInfo != null)
                fieldInfo.SetValue(_culture, persianCalendar);

            FieldInfo info = formatInfo.GetType().GetField("calendar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (info != null)
                info.SetValue(formatInfo, persianCalendar);

            _culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "/";
            _culture.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.NativeNational;
            _culture.NumberFormat.NumberNegativePattern = 0;
        }
        return _culture;
    }
}
```

As you can see in code DateTimeFormat of our custom culture set to date time format of "en-US" culture, at the end _culture variable contain a new culture which is for Persian language but the date time format inherited from US culture.

You need to configure services to use your culture like this :

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture =
            PersianDateExtensionMethods.GetPersianCulture();
```

I don't know where is your problem to change the code for your requirements but i hope this code gives you an idea to solve the problem.